# sys.stdout.writelines("hello") and sys.stdout.write("hello")

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the difference between the following two commands?

```
In [57]: sys.stdout.writelines("hello")                                                                           
hello
In [58]: sys.stdout.write("hello")                                                                                
Out[58]: hello5
```

Comment: A useful Google search phrase might be `python 3.6 stdout.writelines`, which might turn up [this page at Python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=stdout%20writelines)

Answer (score 5):

[`sys.stdout.writelines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) accepts an iterable of strings and writes them to `stdout` one string at a time. Since it does not append newline characters, elements of the iterable will appear to be concatenated if they don't already contain newlines. The return value is `None`.

[`sys.stdout.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) accepts a single string, and writes it to `stdout`. It returns the number of characters written.

The first example (`writelines`) works because a string is an iterable of strings. Each character in the input is written separately. Notice that there is no `Out[57]` because the return value is `None`, but the characters are all printed. They are written individually, but you can't tell because they don't have newlines between them.

The second example (`write`) prints the whole string all at once. Since `write` doesn't append newline characters either, the return value (`5`) is printed immediately after. `Out[58]` is printed because there is a non-`None` return value in this case.

In general, `writelines` was meant to mimic/invert [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines), so normally you could see the difference much better. You would normally call `writelines` with a list or similar iterable, but `write` only accepts a single string (and returns a value):

```
>>> sys.stdout.writelines(['hello\n', 'world\n'])
hello
world

>>> sys.stdout.write('hello\nworld\n')
hello
world
10
```

Barring the return value, for a single string, the result of `writelines` and `write` are indistinguishable. `writelines` is much less efficient though, since it effectively applies `write` to each character individually.